# How to test Stripe based Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

Currently i am trying to develop a native iOS application where i have to integrate Stripe based Apple Pay, For that i have added the SDK provided by them inside my project.

At the final step, i am going to test the apple pay functionality but i am not sure how i can perform it.

1) Do i have to add some dummy / test card account in my Passbook application ?

2) or Do i have to add some real card account in my Passbook application but while payment operation, if i perform any transaction then do it deduct the balance from my account?

3) or Nothing setup is required for Passbook for development purpose

Please guide me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-pay-questions) if you use your test API keys they'll detect it. Here is what it says exactly:

> How do I test Apple Pay with Stripe?
>
> Apple won’t let you add a fake credit card to Passport and the iPhone.
>   However, if you’re using Apple Pay and your test Stripe API keys,
>   we’ll recognize the situation when the Apple Pay request is made and
>   return a successful test card token. To test a payment in live mode,
>   you’ll need to use a working credit card.

Comment: Hi koopajah...my client is asking me to develop SDK like stripe has done for the apple pay, so that his company's name shoukd come in list that apple has recommend to use their SDK...IS IT POSSIBLE?? please share your thought

Comment: Not sure how you become a Payment Platform for Apple Pay, sorry

Comment: Working credit cards on test environment doesn't work. Maybe there should be created Apple Pay Sandbox Tester with Apple Pay test cards, and then use this cards with Strip. Strip API should know about this test cards and allow to use them to test Apple Pay.